# AutoMapper - How to map a concrete domain class to an inherited destination DTO class?

Tags: dns, automapper, dto

I have a flat domain class like this:

```
public class ProductDomain
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

I have two DTO classes like this:

```
public class ProductInfoDTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public string Model{ get; set; }
}

public class ProductDTO : ProductInfoDTO
{        
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string Price { get; set; }
}
```

Now the problem is:

Scenario #1:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDomain, ProductInfoDTO>() // this mapping works fine
```

Scenario #2:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDomain, ProductDTO>() // this mapping is not working and throws System.TypeInitializationException
```

So my question is how to create mapping between ProductDomain and ProductDTO (which inherits ProductInfoDTO) without breaking the definition of both source and destination classes. Also I dont want to introduce any new inheritance for the domain class ProductDomain.

Thanks

Comment: There must be something else going on in your code.  I copy/pasted the code above into a project and it ran just fine.  I even created a sample ProductDomain object and it mapped the data to a ProductDTO without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own custom TypeConverter like this

```
public class ProductDomainToProductDTOConverter : ITypeConverter<ProductDomain, ProductDTO>
{
    public ProductDTO Convert(ProductDomain source)
    {
        ProductDTO product = new ProductDTO();
        product.Price = source.Price;
        ...

        return product;
    }
}
```

And then create a map with your custom TypeConverter like this

```
Mapper.CreateMap<ProductDomain, ProductDTO>().ConvertUsing<ProductDomainToProductDTOConverter>();
```